# How to easily break up a text file into pieces smaller than a threshold?

Tags: linux, emacs, tail, head

I have some text files that are 100 to 300 MB in length that I want to view in Emacs, but my Emacs gets into some performance issues opening and traversing such large files.  Therefore, I'm looking for an easy utility to split a file up into manageable chunks, say 50 MB each and to name the chunks based upon the original name plus some suffix to indicate their location in the sequence.  Each chunk would pick up where the prior one was truncated and be no longer than 50 MB, with the last chunk possibly being shorter.

Is there any easy tool to do such on a Linux computer, perhaps something like head or tail that gives multiple results, one for each chunk?

e.g., given file `test.out` that is 120 MB long, break it up into `test.out.1` for the first 50 MBs, `test.out.2` for the second 50 MBs, and `test.out.3` for the remainder 20 MBs at the end of the file.

I could use combinations of `head` and `tail` to get the pieces, but I'd like a tool that abstracts this all out, perhaps a Perl script or Python script someone has already created to do such a task?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There already is a nice tool for that: `split`

```
> man 1 split 

NAME
     split -- split a file into pieces

SYNOPSIS
     split [-l line_count] [-a suffix_length] [file [prefix]]
     split -b byte_count[K|k|M|m|G|g] [-a suffix_length] [file [prefix]]
     split -p pattern [-a suffix_length] [file [prefix]]
```

`split  --bytes 50M  test.out test.out_` would split the file `test.out` into test.out_xaa, test.out_xab, test.out_xac, ...

A much uglier solution would be to use `dd`

`dd if=test.out of=test.out.part1 bs=1M count=50 skip=0` creates a file named test.out.part1 with the first 50M from test.out. You can increase the value for skip to 1 to get the second chunk, to 2 for the third etc etc. Just make sure to also change the filenames or you will end up overwriting the same output file.

Comment: On at least my Linux, a lowercase 'm' is required for Megabytes.

Comment: Yet another new command learned ☺

Comment: @williamKF: Which flavour of Linux was that? I checked on Ubuntu and FreeBSD. FreeBSD needed the `-b 50M` (No option for --bytes). And Ubuntu accepted both the regular `m` and capital `M`.

Comment: @Hennes `split (coreutils) 5.2.1 February 2011` on my Linux centos4 32 bit 2.6.9-103.ELsmp #1 SMP Fri Dec 9 04:31:51 EST 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux